# How do You Create a Read-Only Dependency Property?

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

How do you create a read-only dependancy property? What are the best-practices for doing so?

Specifically, what's stumping me the most is the fact that there's no implementation of

```
DependencyObject.GetValue()
```

that takes a `System.Windows.DependencyPropertyKey` as a parameter.

`System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly` returns a D`ependencyPropertyKey` object rather than a `DependencyProperty`. So how are you supposed to access your read-only dependency property if you can't make any calls to GetValue? Or are you supposed to somehow convert the `DependencyPropertyKey` into a plain old `DependencyProperty` object?

Advice and/or code would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 162, accepted):

It's easy, actually (via [RegisterReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerreadonly.aspx)):

```
public class OwnerClass : DependencyObject // or DependencyObject inheritor
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ReadOnlyPropPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
            nameof(ReadOnlyProp),
            typeof(int), typeof(OwnerClass),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyPropProperty
        = ReadOnlyPropPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public int ReadOnlyProp
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ReadOnlyPropProperty); }
        protected set { SetValue(ReadOnlyPropPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    //your other code here ...
}
```

You use the key only when you set the value in private/protected/internal code. Due to the protected `ReadOnlyProp` setter, this is transparent to you.

Comment: Can you please one real time example or requirement where we use, this ReadOnly dependency property?

Comment: @RahulSonone anytime you don't want the property to be set from outside the control class. If you don't make it read only, you can set it in XAML etc.

Comment: ActualWidth/ActualHeight of any control are one good example.

Comment: You might want to update `"ReadOnlyProp"` to `nameof(ReadOnlyProp)` because a lot of people probably copy/paste this and they might as well use the current & improved syntax.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggestion. To be honest, this is an old answer and I am not "maintaining" updated versions of answers myself. Also, these days I'm much more on javascript than C#.

Answer (score 2):

I want to note that at the current time it is better to use https://github.com/HavenDV/DependencyPropertyGenerator, the code will be extremely simple:

```cs
[DependencyProperty<int>("ReadOnlyProperty", IsReadOnly = true)]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
}
```